# how to use multiple variables into ng-mouseleave directive

Tags: angularjs

I have two angular controller variables `addcommentfabactionbar.clicked` and `addcommentfabactionbar.hover` (addcommentfabactionbar is an alias of controller).
I want to assign both variable in `ng-mouseleave` directive.

```
ng-mouseleave="addcommentfabactionbar.clicked = false, addcommentfabactionbar.hover = false"
```

But i am getting angular syntax error,

```
angular.min.js:107 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=addcommentfabactionbar&p…is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=40&p3=addcommentfabactionbar.clicked%20%3DNaNalse%20addcommentfabactionbar.hover%20%3D%false&p4=addcommentfabactionbar.hover%20%3D%false
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: try sending the data as a object array `{addcommentfabactionbar.clicked = false, addcommentfabactionbar.hover = false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `;`(semicolon) instead of `,`(comma). I believe you wanted to perform multiple operation at the same time, so you could separate each operation by `;`.

```
ng-mouseleave="addcommentfabactionbar.clicked= false;addcommentfabactionbar.hover = false"
```

Or to make HTML cleaner, you could do the same from `controller` method, only you just need to call method by passing `addcommentfabactionbar` object.

```
ng-mouseleave="myFunction(addcommentfabactionbar)"

$scope.myFunction = function(addcommentfabactionbar){
    addcommentfabactionbar.clicked = false;
    addcommentfabactionbar.hover = false;
}
```